# Sed command to extract substring of character separated words in a string

Tags: sed, substring, separator

Given a string such as `abc-def-ghi-jkl`.
Can the `sed` command extract the substring to the left of the nth separator character such as `abc` for 1, `abd-def` for 2 etc?

I need it for making creating files based on a subset of the computers hostname, normally `abc-def-xyz.domain.com`.

Having looked around it appears that `awk`, `cut` and `sed` are combined in this kind of extractions but I prefer something that can be used as part of a command line.

Comment: Does it *need* to be `sed`? Have you considered using `cut`?

Comment: @MarkByers I have edited to allow more options, usability in a shell command is main requirement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cut`is your friend:

```
$ echo "abc-def-ghi-jkl" | cut -d- -f1
abc
$ echo "abc-def-ghi-jkl" | cut -d- -f-2
abc-def
$ echo "abc-def-ghi-jkl" | cut -d- -f-3
abc-def-ghi
$ echo "abc-def-ghi-jkl" | cut -d- -f-4
abc-def-ghi-jkl
```

other possibilities:

```
$ echo "abc-def-ghi-jkl" | cut -d- -f2
def
$ echo "abc-def-ghi-jkl" | cut -d- -f3
ghi
$ echo "abc-def-ghi-jkl" | cut -d- -f4
jkl
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
LEVELS=3;
echo "abc-def-ghi-jkl" | awk -F '-' "{x=$LEVELS; n=1; ORS=\"\"; while (n<=x) {print \$n; if (n<x) print \"-\"; n=n+1; }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
a=1;b=2;c=3;d=4
echo "abc-def-ghi-jkl" | sed 's/-/\n/'"$a"';s/\n.*//'          
abc
echo "abc-def-ghi-jkl" | sed 's/-/\n/'"$b"';s/\n.*//'
abc-def
echo "abc-def-ghi-jkl" | sed 's/-/\n/'"$c"';s/\n.*//'
abc-def-ghi
echo "abc-def-ghi-jkl" | sed 's/-/\n/'"$d"';s/\n.*//'
abc-def-ghi-jkl
```